# Setting the state several times inside useEffect sets the last one only

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I got a component which has a form to add a new item and its supposed to also update an existing item. I'm trying to set the value of the form fields such that if a user chooses to edit an item, he will have all of the data of the existing item already in the form, which he just needs to edit.

I'm using `useEffect` for that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.editedItem)
    {
        inputChangedHandler(props.editedItem.companyName, "company");
        inputChangedHandler(props.editedItem.name, "name");
        inputChangedHandler(props.editedItem.description, "description");
    }
  }, [props.editedItem])
```

the method `inputChangedHandler` is setting the form value of a specific field (company, name, description):

```
const inputChangedHandler = (newVal, inputIdentifier) => 
{
    const updatedOrderForm = {
        ...formSettings
    };
    const updatedFormElement = { 
        ...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier]
    };
    updatedFormElement.value = newVal;
    updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier] = updatedFormElement;
    setFormSettings(updatedOrderForm);
}
```

The problem here is that only the last field is changed (description in the case of the code). If I changed the lines order and the "name" will be the last, the name info will appear and not the description.

How can I fix it?

Comment: show `inputChangedHandler` method pls

Comment: Added the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be **overriding** your form with staled values (due to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)).

```
// closure on `updatedOrderForm` value, staled state
const updatedFormElement = { 
   ...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier]
};
```

Try using [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) which provides **the most updated** state.

```
const inputChangedHandler = (newVal, inputIdentifier) => {
  setFormSettings((prev) => {
    const updatedOrderForm = {
      ...formSettings,
    };

    const updatedFormElement = {
      ...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier],
      value: newVal,
    };

    return { ...prev, [inputIdentifier]: updatedFormElement };
  });
};
```

Comment: That was indeed the case

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it matter if I use the spread operator like you did or keep setting the value and the updatedFormElement separately like I did in my original code?

Comment: They both have the same effect, but what you did is error-prone because it will work only if you mutate a **copy** of a state `...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier]` (makes a shallow copy). See https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how is your `inputChangedHandler` method definition is but you can take the value and use the respective hook to set it.

```
function inputChangedHandler({companyName,name, description}){
  setName(name);
  setCompanyName(companyName);
  ...

}
 useEffect(() => {
    if(props.editedItem)
    {
        inputChangedHandler(...props.editedItem);
    }
  }, [props.editedItem])
```

Comment: What is the difference between calling a method with all the sets and having it inside the use effect?

Comment: I'm Not sure how is your inputChangedHandler method definition. can you provide more info on the method?

Comment: can you post your useState hooks for setting name, description and other values

Comment: That's in the method I added.. the last line is setting a new value to a specific field